# Use CSS3 Shapes as centered backgrounds

Tags: html, css

I want to have my UL have half triangles as their background. I would really like to use only CSS shapes for this project. I have used some code form this [site](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), however I need some additional help. I am unable to have the text centered in the shapes.  What can I adjust to accomplish this?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/akAh9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swapping

```
right: 6em;
```

... for ...

```
right: 50%;
```

... seems to do the trick (with this you effectively move the lower point of that CSS triangle to the middle of the `.diamond` element).

Comment: also instead of defining a `right` define `margin-left:-50%;`

Comment: I tried to apply the same thing to a diamond and it didn't work. Here is the unmodified code: http://jsfiddle.net/ekmfE/ What should I do here?